# replacing google play console appbundle .aab with one with the same version number

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

I uploaded my app to play store recently as .aab bundle with version code 3.6، after full rollout my app is succssfully published on play store, now my problem is that after publishing I discovered that the app is not working correctly with some locals eg "Arabic, Hebrew" so I created another aab file to fix the problem but unfortunately I forget to change the version number, to make the issue worse my workstation got corrupted hard drive and it's refusing to boot and my upload signing keys are not part of source control so I can't create new aab with 3.7 as version.
usually when the app is not published I can delete the release and then delete the appbundle from bundle explorer and reupload with same version.

Can I as desperate resort delete the app completely and reupload the same aab after creating new app?

Can I talk to google play store support and ask them to remove the release?

I tried to revert to a previous release 3.5 so that I can delete
the currently active one but with no luck
google play says I cannot revert to 3.5 because it doesn't allow users to upgrade!

Update: I just contacted google play support and asked them to change my upload signing keys, I had to wait for 48 hours until the keys became active.

Comment: You can not delete an uploaded .aab you always upload a new one .aab  file with different version

Comment: You can actually delete aab from bundle explorer after deleting release first and then reupload one with the same version